# Running a Flask App in docker doesn't show a page in browser

Tags: python, docker, flask

I created the following Flask app:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a beautiful world indeed</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

COPY . app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR app

EXPOSE 5000:5000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Then I created the image and run it:

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -t -i myimage
```

But when I receive the link, I click on it `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000` and it takes me to a browser. However, nothing displays. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix here.

1. You should be binding to `0.0.0.0` if you want the container to be accessible from the outside
2. You should bind the port when running docker

So modify the Python file to have the following:

```py
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

and then:

```bash
$ docker build -t myimage .
$ docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 myimage
```

Comment: thanks, well explained answer

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPOSE` keyword [doesn't actually make it so the port is published at runtime](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)
Try:

```
docker run -t -i myimage -p 5000:5000
```